# Global Search Bar Not Working For Salesforce CMS Articles (Experience Cloud)

Tags: global-search, experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

I have an experience cloud website that uses Salesforce CMS. In production when users enter keywords in the Global Peer-To-Peer Search Bar, the auto-complete function shows CMS articles matching those keywords:

[image: Auto complete of CMS Articles in Global Search Bar]

When they click on the names of the autocompleted articles they can read them, and it works perfectly fine. The issue happens when I try to do the same from a Sandbox org. In this case, the search bar takes me to the standard Record Detail page (not the detail page of the article) showing this error:

```
Looks like there's a problem.

INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'ManagedContentVersion' is not supported in describeCompactLayouts.
```

[image: Record Detail page error for Salesforce CMS Articles]

The production instance is running  Summer '21 and the Sandbox is running Winter '22. I suspect this is because of the update in the sandbox. I've checked the release notes and trailheads and couldn't find anything about this. The settings in production and in the sandbox are the same as well.

Any idea about how to solve this would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Emmanuel-m I'm having a customer community and CMS content is not appeared in Global Search Results. Any idea?
I have enabled search in the channel and added Content into Global Search Results.